# Parsing date/time strings which are not 'standard' formats

Tags: time, go

How do I parse non-standard date/time strings in Go. In example if I wanted to convert the string `10/15/1983` into a `time.Time`? The `time.Parse()` function supposedly allows you to specify a format.

http://play.golang.org/p/v5DbowXt1x

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    test, err := time.Parse("10/15/1983", "10/15/1983")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

This results in a panic.

`panic: parsing time "10/15/1983" as "10/15/1983": cannot parse "" as "0/"`

Logically that makes sense because how is it supposed to know which is the day and which is the month.

Other languages have a function similar to the following:

`parse("mm/dd/yyyy", "10/15/1983")`

I cannot find such a function in the Go docs, is my only choice to regex?

Comment: You might want to look at [this blog](http://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2011/05/go_time.html) by Paul Smith

Answer (score 180, accepted):

There are some key values that the time.Parse is looking for.

By changing:

```
test, err := time.Parse("10/15/1983", "10/15/1983")
```

to

```
test, err := time.Parse("01/02/2006", "10/15/1983")
```

the parser will recognize it.

Here's the [modified code on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/tPr45KHNbF).

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    test, err := time.Parse("01/02/2006", "10/15/1983")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

You can utilize the constants list in the [src/pkg/time/format.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/format.go) file to create your own parse formats.

```
const (
    stdLongMonth      = "January"
    stdMonth          = "Jan"
    stdNumMonth       = "1"
    stdZeroMonth      = "01"
    stdLongWeekDay    = "Monday"
    stdWeekDay        = "Mon"
    stdDay            = "2"
    stdUnderDay       = "_2"
    stdZeroDay        = "02"
    stdHour           = "15"
    stdHour12         = "3"
    stdZeroHour12     = "03"
    stdMinute         = "4"
    stdZeroMinute     = "04"
    stdSecond         = "5"
    stdZeroSecond     = "05"
    stdLongYear       = "2006"
    stdYear           = "06"
    stdPM             = "PM"
    stdpm             = "pm"
    stdTZ             = "MST"
    stdISO8601TZ      = "Z0700"  // prints Z for UTC
    stdISO8601ColonTZ = "Z07:00" // prints Z for UTC
    stdNumTZ          = "-0700"  // always numeric
    stdNumShortTZ     = "-07"    // always numeric
    stdNumColonTZ     = "-07:00" // always numeric
)
```

So anytime your format specifies a year, it should be done with "06" or "2006", seconds are specified by "05" or "5" and time zones are specified at "MST", "Z0700", "Z07:00", "-0700", "-07" or "-07:00".  If you reference the constants list you can likely put together any standard format you'd need to parse.

For example, if you want to parse the date/time in the [Common Log Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format), the format Apache uses for its log files, you would do so by passing the following string to `time.Parse()` as the *layout* argument.

```
"02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700"
```

"02" denotes the day of the month field, "Jan" denotes the month name field, "2006" denotes the year field, "15" denotes the hour of day field in 24 hour format, "04" denotes the minutes field, "05" denotes the seconds field and "-0700" denotes the time zone field.

That format would parse the current PST time: `31/Dec/2012:15:32:25 -0800`

So the `time.Parse()` call would look like this:

```
test, err := time.Parse("02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700", "31/Dec/2012:15:32:25 -0800")
```

Comment: Your code works, but why? If I change it to `time.Parse("01/02/2005", "10/15/1983")` it fails... what is magic about 2006 as opposed to 2005, 2004, 1990 etc?

Comment: Upon re-reading the docs I think this point could be made a bit more clearly in them. I couple real world examples would make it much clearer. In my futile attempts I tried things like `time.Parse("stdLongMonth/stdLongDay/stdLongYear", "10/15/83")` =p.

Comment: Wow, the Go docs could have mentioned that the numbers you use in your date format actually matter.

Comment: Hi Nuncleon. You made 2 mistakes there. First of all you selected wrong constants for your format: should be stdZeroMonth/stdZeroDay/stdYear and second thing that you need to use the values of this constants. So for your case you need to parse like this: `time.Parse("01/02/06", "10/15/83")`

Comment: What a sneaky approach! Thank you for explaining it! +1

Comment: It's not possible to format a 24 hour format *without leading zeroes*?

Comment: thanks for the explanation really interesting implementation.

Comment: This a wonderful answer and  cleared all my doubts about the time package

Answer (score 8):

If you can't remember the Numbers in the specifying layout ("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"), you may use my simple date formatting library [github.com/metakeule/fmtdate](https://github.com/metakeule/fmtdate) that uses MS Excel conventions, like Y,M,D,h and internally translates them to the number format:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/metakeule/fmtdate"

    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    test, err := fmtdate.Parse("MM/DD/YYYY", "10/15/1983")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

Comment: For people that can't remember, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 (01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -07)?? At least something like a strftime format string has support for more things, your spreadsheet format doesn't even have 12 hour am/pm support so is a step backwards in several ways.

Comment: @DaveC  Well we Germans don't think in am/pm, so 15 to 3 is a mindshift, also you   must remember the order: Day, Month, Hour/PM, Minute, Second, Year, Timezone. The position of the year is weird. However I always had to look it up and I am not the only one.... Also for someone not familiar with the go time format, the excel format is obviously a format and can't be confused with a real date.

Comment: @DaveC I have updated the library to support time zones and AM/PM. Anything missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a C-Style formatting function: After reviewing some of the options I have chosen https://github.com/cactus/gostrftime as it generally follows the strfmt(3) notation.

To quote the example:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/cactus/gostrftime"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(gostrftime.Format("%Y-%m-%d", now))
}
```

If a date format has to be used by both C and Go and the C implementation is not to be touched there's no choice but to adapt on the Go end. The above package fulfills that need.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want bother remembering the magic numbers, you can do this:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   var (
      y, d int
      m time.Month
   )
   fmt.Sscanf("10/15/1983", "%v/%v/%v", &m, &d, &y)
   t := time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
   fmt.Println(t) // 1983-10-15 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sscanf