# How to filter by date/time in Google App Engine Datastore using GoLang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a golang backend run on Google App Engine. I have an Entity called `Recruit` that has a property

```
UpdatedAt time.Time `datastore:"updated_at"`
```

I would like to query Recruits by their updated time. My first instinct is to use a [filter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Filters).

```
query = datastore.NewQuery("Recruit").Filter("updated_at <=", updatedAt)
```

where updatedAt is a string. I've tried the forms `2014-08-28 01:53:19` and `2014-08-28T01:53:19.00618Z` (The former is the form the time.Time property takes in the datastore, while the latter is how it propagates in JSON.)

When I call the query with `<=`, all Recruit objects are returned. When calling with `>=`, null is returned. I'm quite sure I'm testing with a time in the middle of the data set.

When I test on console.developers.google.com, the console filters support `a date and time` `after/before`, but trying to replace `<=` with `after` results in an error.

Has anyone managed to filter queries by date or time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use updatedAt of type time.Time instead of as a string

Following is a snippet of how I managed to filter queries by time:

My Property:

```
TimeStamp time.Time
```

My Query:

```
timeNow := time.Now()
time1hr := timeNow.Add(-59*time.Minute)
q := datastore.NewQuery("Recruit").Filter("TimeStamp <=", time1hr)
```

This code would give me all the entities before time1hr.

Comment: You may also find time.Parse handy in this situation. Here is a good SO answer showing it's usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106541/go-parsing-date-time-strings-which-are-not-standard-formats

Comment: That worked! I started storing the time as an int, just as a work around, but this is much better. Should have expected that the filter parameter need be of the same type. @JoeBergevin, I did use parse. Worked like a charm.