# Calculating deltas between two dates in years, days, hours, mins etc

Tags: datetime, go

I'm working on a Golang example that requires some date calculations. I was rather hoping that Go would provide some nice date libraries similar to the excellent Python `datetime` module, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

How can I represent this python example in Go ?

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2013, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2018, 9, 26)
delta = d0 - d1
print delta.days
>>-1865
```

I've spent a fair bit of time looking around on how to do this I can't seem to find a definitive answer that is clear and concise and without caveats such as not properly calculating leap years etc.

This seems to be a fairly big limitation to what is becoming an excellent little language for building cross platform prototypes and eventually production applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you've spent your fair bit of time looking and not finding anything, but the [`time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) package of the standard library has everything you want.

Here is your example coded in Go:

```
d0 := time.Date(2013, 8, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
d1 := time.Date(2018, 9, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

delta := d0.Sub(d1)

fmt.Println(delta.Hours() / 24)
```

Output (as expected):

```
-1865
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/LxufPaEjG9).

Comment: Hmm, nice thank you. I can't believe I missed that. Is there a `time.strptime(string[, format])`  e.g. `time.strptime('11/24/2013', "%m/%d/%Y")` equivalent ?

Comment: @user1513388 Yes, there is. Check out the [`time.Parse()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) function.

Comment: Thanks I've been just trying that. 

I've been hitting this issue though when trying to parse dates like this "24/11/2013" or this "11/24/2013" 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106541/go-parsing-date-time-strings-which-are-not-standard-formats though which is rather confusing.

Comment: @user1513388 I don't think it's confusing. First you have to specify the format/layout in which the parseable input is presented. This is done by specifying a predefined date in using the format you want to parse: `time.Parse("01/02/2006", "10/15/1983")` - first is the reference date, 2nd is the input `string` containing the date you want to parse.

Comment: Yeah get that bit but how can I parse a european formatted date. This fails: 

fmt.Print(time.Parse("23/02/06", "15/06/13")) with 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC parsing time "15/06/13" as "23/02/06": cannot parse "/06/13" as "3"

Comment: @user1513388 Looks you don't fully grasped it. The layout **must** contain the reference date formatted which is `2006-01-02`. And you specified `2006-02-26` - that is not a valid layout.

Comment: Arr OK. Thanks this works now fmt.Print(time.Parse("02/01/06", "23/10/13")) >> 2013-10-23 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>. Only other question is what does the <nil> mean ?

Comment: @user1513388 Please check the documentation of [`time.Parse()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse). It returns 2 values, the 2nd one is an `error` which will be `nil` if parsing succeeds.

Comment: Thanks very much - its starting to make sense to me now.