# How to use multiple formats to parse dates in a loop?

Tags: go

I am trying to read a huge csv file with a date column having value in 2 possible formats which are non-standard...

1. 12/28/2015 -- mm/**dd**/yyyy
2. 11/2/2013  -- mm/**d**/yyyy

...meaning the middle day component can be single or double digit.

I learnt how to use format from this nice old question: [Parsing date/time strings which are not 'standard' formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106541/parsing-date-time-strings-which-are-not-standard-formats). But since i am going in a loop trying to parse each row, i can specify only one format to be used at a time. Now it errors on finding date value of different format. Maybe i can code to catch error when parse-using-format#1 fails and then apply format#2, rather than erroring out. But could someone please point me to a better/correct way?

A sample code with array of date strings: https://play.golang.org/p/aloIQnrkOjK

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const format = "01/02/2006" //mm/dd/yyyy
    var list [2]string = [2]string{"12/28/2015", "11/2/2013"}
    for _, data := range list {
        t, err := time.Parse(format, data)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error is: ", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Value is: ", t)
        }
    }
}
```

//Output:

Value is:  2015-12-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Error is:  parsing time "11/2/2013" as "01/02/2006": cannot parse "2/2013" as "02"

Comment: Here is an example on how you could do that: https://github.com/spf13/cast/blob/master/caste.go#L1206. Even better, you can use this library to get this functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: Inside the loop if `err` is `nil`, then return, don't proceed to the next format. Only try more (next) format if there's an error. After the loop, if none of the formats worked, then return an error.

Comment: `"01/2/2006"` parses both of these strings without error. Even a leading zero is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. I found @Peter 's solution, out of these comments, to be easiest. Didn't know that we could use '2' to represent single+double digits of month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question parses multiple dates with a single format.  The problem is that one of the dates does not match the format (missing leading zero on day).  Fix by making the leading zero optional:

```
const format = "1/2/2006" // remove zero before day (and month just in case)
```